# What is the probability that the second head is received as the fourth coin?

Tags: probability

Suppose that we have an unfair coin and suppose also that
$$
P(H) = 0.6 \quad \& \quad P(T)=0.4.
$$
We also know that each tossing is independent of the preceding ones. Now, let us toss the coin four times.

**My question:** What is the probability that the second head is received as the fourth coin?

**My attempt:** We need to use conditional probability.
\begin{align}
&  P(4th \ coin = H \ | \ 1st \ coin = H, \ 2nd \ coin = T, \ 3rd \ coin = T) \ + \\ 
&  P(4th \ coin = H \ | \ 1st \ coin = T, \ 2nd \ coin = H, \ 3rd \ coin = T) \ + \\
&  P(4th \ coin = H \ | \ 1st \ coin = T, \ 2nd \ coin = T, \ 3rd \ coin = H)
\end{align}

But I found this sum greater than 1. Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, $$\begin{aligned}\text{Required probability} &= P(\text{1 Head occurs at any one of the 3 coins before fourth coin}) \times P(\text{Fourth coin gives a Head}) \\ &= ^3C_1 \times P(H) \times P(T)^2 \times P(H) \\ &= 3 \times 0.6 \times 0.4^2 \times 0.6 \\ &= 0.288 \times 0.6 \\ &= 0.1728 \end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you, I got it :)

Comment: The required probability is the probability that exactly one head occurs during the first three tosses *multiplied* by the probability that the fourth coin results in a head.

Comment: Ahh, I agree, made a glaring error there... :-(